# How to prevent Kindle Paperwhite turning itself off?

Tags: technology

The Kindle Paperwhite must a contender for worst designed product!

The on/off switch is at the bottom, like this:

[image]

so when I use it at a lunch counter and sit it on the counter, it constantly powers off.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Why don't you rotate the display to horizontal or top-for-bottom so the power switch is either on the side or the top?

Comment: Get a case for the kindle and that will protect the power button from being pressed.

Comment: O'rly? Know you of such a case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the power button gets triggered when it's upright on a table because the table is hard. So find a small soft cloth, like a wash cloth (ideal), a scarf, or a napkin. Fold that over itself a few times to make a soft base. Set that on the table, and set the device on top of it. The soft surface shouldn't press very hard against the button, so it *shouldn't* turn itself off.

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking that someone would sell a clip-on piece of plastic. I will try your suggestion, although it is sub-optimal as I now have to carry something else around. If I don't get a better solution, I will do that. Thanks

Comment: I was envisioning that you were at a counter at a restaurant, and you could just get a few paper napkins from the server. But if you're not at a restaurant, you'd either have to bring something with you (sub-optimal for sure!) or find something to use in your current environment.

Comment: paper napkins are a good idea :-)

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica buying a special accessory kind of goes against the philosophy of life hacks - find a quick-and-dirty solution by thinking outside the box ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you rotate the display?

Step 1

Press the "Menu" button. On models with an integrated keyboard, press the "Aa" button instead.

On the Kindle Paperwhite, the Menu button is now a Home icon (it looks like a house), which appears on a toolbar at the top of the screen. If you're reading a book or other content and don't see the toolbar, simply tap at the top of the screen to make it appear.

Step 2

Use the 5-Way navigational controller to highlight "Screen Rotation" and press the center button to select it.

Highlight one of the four orientation options with the 5-Way controller and press the center button to select it. The options are graphically displayed, indicated portrait or landscape mode, with the buttons located top, bottom, left or right.

Some books with illustrations will automatically appear horizontally so you might wish to reorient them using this procedure.

Comment: This sounds like a really good idea (upvote). Unfortunately, the Paperwhite (my model, at least) doe snot have  an integrated keyboard, or a 5-Way controller , but if there is any way to do this via the settings menu, I would love to hear it

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica No Menu button?

Comment: There is a menu icon, not a button (I am not seeking to split hairs, just to clarify). From that, I don't see how to do what you suggest :-(

Comment: Aha, I found the "`Aa`" icon.  It only allows portrait or landscape. I can't see me reading landscape, though. What a pity that I can't rotate 180 :-(